# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm using this code:

```
if imgAct < len(limg):
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path+limg[imgAct]))
    f=etiq.config(image = img)
    f.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    f.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
```

But I get this error:

> **`AttributeError`:** `NoneType` object has no attribute `pack`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Reverting. Please don't make changes to the questions that render answers incorrect, especially when it's clear the new question is bogus (`NoneType` does _not_ have a `config` method). Feel free to _augment_ your question with further information, or ask a new question if it's only tangentially related.

Answer (score 6):

`f` is being set to `None` in the call:

```
f = etiq.config (image = img)
```

and that's what's causing the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

when you do the `f.pack()`.

You need to sort that `None` return value out. With that particular aspect, I can't help, since a cursory google for `etiq` turns up [*"For women who want to be empowered with credible facts about estrogen therapy"*](http://www.etiq.info/), which I'm pretty certain is unrelated to the library you're using :-)

Comment: If `etiq` is a `Label` object, then I suggest to try `etiq.pack` instead of `f.pack`, because (according to [this reference](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method)) method `config` returns `None` if any arguments were passed.